# how to get value from other method in C#

Tags: c#

as the title said, I have a problem getting my variable value into other method. because I want to call it in another class
My ViewModel Class

```
public VModel()
    { 
        DataTable s = new DataTable();

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=library;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;"))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            var b = (int)ClickedCommand2.Name;
            adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from anime_list where id_movie = '"+ (int)ClickedCommand2.Name +"'", connection);
            adapter.Fill(s);
        }
        Selected = s.DefaultView;
        Clicked2 = new ClickedCommand2(this);
    }
```

Clicked Class

```
public class ClickedCommand2 : ICommand
{
    private VModel _vModel;

    public ClickedCommand2(VModel vModel)
    {
        _vModel = vModel;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public int a;
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var id_movie = (int)parameter;
        var rowIndex = id_movie - 1;
        a = (int)(_vModel.Library2[rowIndex]["id_movie"]);
    }

    private static int b = a;
    public static int Name
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }

    }
}
```

EDIT : the question is how to get A value into my viewmodel class

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Your A value is only in scope of Execute. Declare var a outstide of the method to make it accessible outside of the method.

Comment: @JoshAdams can you add an example? im a bit new to c#

Comment: `NameOfYourClass.Name = 99` and that will set `b` to 99.

Comment: @CodingYoshi but A value is different whether i click on something? because im getting A value from sql data

Comment: @Hans added an example, hope that helps. comment if i can clarify any further :) best of luck

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You need to provide more details.

Comment: @CodingYoshi detail added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `(_vModel.Library2[rowIndex]["id_movie"])` is an integer, you can make the scope outside of Execute:

```
  public class ClickedCommand2 : ICommand
{
    private VModel _vModel;

    public ClickedCommand2(VModel vModel)
    {
        _vModel = vModel;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private static int a;
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var id_movie = (int)parameter;
        var rowIndex = id_movie - 1;
        a = (int)(_vModel.Library2[rowIndex]["id_movie"]);
    }

    private static int b = a;
    public static int Name
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }

    }
}
```

Comment: a field initializer cannot references to static field it says? on `private static int b = a;`

Comment: fixed for you, make a static

Comment: it works, but it show nothing on my viewmodel class when it clicked or selected, if i change to number that i define it works